# Spring Boot replaces its hostname with docker container id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, netflix-eureka

I setup a simple Spring Boot application with Security with Keycloak that is running as a service with eureka, gateway api etc.. All of them are dockerized.
I created an endpoint which returns a String and is secured by SecurityFilterChain:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        httpSecurity
                .sessionManagement(Customizer.withDefaults());
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize
                            .requestMatchers("/keycloak-test", "/tournament/keycloak-test").fullyAuthenticated()
                            .anyRequest().permitAll();
                });
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

The endpoint:

```java
    @GetMapping("/keycloak-test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
    }
```

When I'm trying to access this endpoint I expected the redirect to login form or to keycloak itself, but the thing is that I'm being redirected to the containerId:port:
`http://6e375582a097:8201/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-provider` thus "Server Not Found" error.

My application.yml:

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://172.18.0.1:8762/eureka
server:
  port: 8201
  error:
    include-message: always
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://172.18.0.1:5501/tournament
    username: username
    password: ${DB_STG_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 10000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      idle-timeout: 5000
      max-lifetime: 1000
      auto-commit: true
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    enabled: true
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak-provider:
            issuer-uri: https://keycloak.example.com/realms/keycloak-realm
        registration:
          aimcup:
            provider: keycloak-provider
            client-name: keycloak-provider
            client-id: keycloak-provider
            client-secret: 
            scope: profile,openid,offline_access
            redirect-uri: https://example.com/keycloak-test
```

I'd like to mention that I'm also using a nginx proxy manager.

I tried to look through all filters and check when the redirect uri is being determined, but none cought my eye.
Setting `server.address` property in `application.yml` to my `example.com` also did not work.

Is it because of eureka has a container id instead of its IP address?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring Boot 3, set `forward-headers-strategy` to `native` and it works as intended:

`server.forward-headers-strategy: native`